# Best Approximation in Operator/non-Frobenius Norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, operator-theory, convex-optimization

Since the Frobenius norm on matrices is generated by an inner product, solving the optimization/approximation problem of approximating an operator $X$ with a scalar multiple of another operator $Y$
$$\text{minimize:}\,\|X-\alpha Y\|_\mathsf{F}$$
has a closed form solution $\alpha = \frac{\langle X, Y \rangle}{\langle Y,Y \rangle}$ via an orthogonal projection.

What if I want to consider a non-Frobenius norm, specifically the standard operator norm / spectral norm / 2-norm? In other words, is there a closed form and/or efficient solution to the optimization problem
$$\text{minimize:}\,\|X-\alpha Y\|_2$$
Since $\|A\|_2\leq \|A\|_\mathsf{F}$ for all $A$, solving the Frobenius version would provide an upper bound for the operator norm approximation. Is this approximation decent?

It feels like you could frame this problem as a semidefinite program under the self-adjoint assumption, but a closed form solution would be more optimal.

Comment: The value for the Frobenius approximation can be about $\sqrt n$ off the true minimum for $n\times n$ matrices (consider $X=\operatorname{diag}(1,0,\dots,0)$ and $Y=\operatorname{diag}(1,a,\dots,a)$ with $a\approx n^{-1/2}$). An **exact** explicit formula for the minimizer is certainly out of question. The rest depends on how much you are willing to settle with.

Comment: A simple SDP formulation is:
\begin{equation*}
  \min_{a,t}\quad t\quad \text{s.t.}\quad\begin{bmatrix}tI & X-aY\\ (X-aY)^* & tI \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks to you both! In my specific application, $X=I$ and $Y$ is positive definitie. I'm trying to make $I-\alpha Y$ the optimal contraction under a submultiplicative norm. Looking into the $\|A\|_2 \leq \|A\|_\mathsf{F} \leq \sqrt{n}\|A\|_2$ bound, I can ensure that $\|A\|_\mathsf{F} \leq 1$ if the condition number $\kappa(Y) < \frac{1 + n^{-1/2}}{1 - n^{-1/2}}$. That's probably good enough as a start.

Comment: But in this special case, minimizing $\|I-aY\|$ is the same as minimizing $\|I-aD\|$ where the $D$ is the diagonal of eigenvalues of $Y$; and the minimum of this problem is trivial!